# CSS div moves when when zooming

Tags: css, html, layout

I am trying to arrange a grid layout.

The last div moves when zooming out. Also a white line appear between the right side panel and last content div when I zoom in.

Am I doing something crucially wrong with my CSS and layout?

Cheers,
Owain

---

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 827px;
    height: 580px;
    float: left;
}

.side-pannel {
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 580px;
    background-color: #ba55d3;
    float: left;
}

.two-item-column {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.column-border-middle {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.item1 {
    width: 206px;
    height: 288px;
    background: #666; 
}
.item2 {
    width: 206px;
    height: 291px;
    background: #666;
    border-top: 1px solid black; 
}
```

---

```
<div class="side-pannel" id="left-pannel"></div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="two-item-column" >
        <div class="item1 column-border-middle"></div>
        <div class="item2 column-border-middle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="two-item-column" >
        <div class="item1 column-border-middle"></div>
        <div class="item2 column-border-middle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="two-item-column" >
        <div class="item1 column-border-middle"></div>
        <div class="item2 column-border-middle"></div>
    </div>
       <div class="two-item-column" >
        <div class="item1"></div>
        <div class="item2"></div>
    </div>   
</div>
<div class="side-pannel" id="right-pannel"></div>
```

Comment: You've given fixed values to your `div`s.

Comment: Which div should I target to remove the width/height from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding width to `two-item-column` would fix it.  And there is no need to make its position relative if it is not for other parts of your layout:

```
.two-item-column {
    float: left;
    width: 207px;
}

.two-item-column:last-child {
    width: 206px;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why this fixed the issue?

Comment: 1 more thing, I still see white lines when zooming in on the vertical borders.

Comment: I'm not sure myself why exactly, but setting a width where we know the exact value fix probable problems of other tags :P  Maybe it was because of some unset margin, padding or border on items.  Try to set margin and padding for every element. Maybe it fixes the vertical space.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/q8uBG/4/) is what your [output](http://jsfiddle.net/q8uBG/4/embedded/result/) should be.

The CSS shall be

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 88%;
    height: 580px;
    float: left;
}
.side-pannel {
    position: relative;
    width: 6%;
    height: 580px;
    background-color: #ba55d3;
    float: left;
}
.two-item-column {
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

also, remove the `width` attribute/property from `.item1` and `.item2`.